# mongoose deep query in array within a populated field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

these are models:

```
const pageSchema = new Schema 
({
        name: 
        {
            type:String,
            unique:false,
            required:false,
            trim:false,
            min:3,
            max:15
        }
        pageCategory:
        {
            type:Schema.ObjectId,
            ref:'PageCategory',
            required:true
        }
 })
`
`const pageCategorySchema = new Schema
(
    {
        name:
        {
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        topics:
        [{
            type:Schema.ObjectId,
            ref:'Topic',
            required:false
        }]
    }
)
```

and I need a query to get all pages that has pageCategories.topics within ID sent on query like this:

```
async function getTopicPages(topic)
{
    
const topicPages = await Page.find({'pageCategory.topics':{$eq:topic}})
.populate:('pageCategory','user')

    try 
    {
        return topicPages
        
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message)
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work, return empty array and I now there are pages with pagecategory topics that include a topic sent on query. ???

Comment: Hi, `pageCategory.topics` field is an array, do you try `$in`? Because `$eq` cannot check correctly. `topics` is an array and `topic` is single object, not equal. Try this maybe work; `{$in: [topic]}` instead `{$eq:topic}`

Comment: Hi Jose, I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve. I suggest you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and clarify your question. So that more people can help you.

Comment: @MuhammedİKİNCİ and Quethzel Diaz  Thank you for you help, but it doesnt works, please if you can see this next link, I explain there another perspective about same difficult.             Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612336/mongoose-query-embedded-document-mongoose-graphql